# Passing List of objects by appending it in jquery formdata

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, form-data

i came across a scenario in MVC 4 where i need to send an image along with list of objects in ajax call. How can i append it in formData?
here is my formdata and ajax call

```
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var imgFile = document.getElementById('ProfilePic');
    var imgfileList = imgFile.files;
    formdata.append(imgfileList[0].name, imgfileList[0]);

    // Below Code is not workin
    formdata.append('Rent', $scope.RentTypes);
    // $scope.RentType = [{ id:1,price:5},{id:2,price:6}]

        $.ajax({
            url: url
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST'
        });
```

In controller, my action which is get called from ajax call is like this

```
  public ActionResult Upload(List<Rent> Rent)
{
}
```

Rent.cs

```
public class Rent
{
 public int id;
 public int price;
 public Available;
}
```

Comment: In order to bind to `(List<Rent> Rent)` it would need to be something like `formdata.append({ '[0].id':1, '[0].price':5, '[1].id':2, '[1].price':6 });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I thought formdata would take 2 agruments, i will try it and let you know stephen if it works

Comment: Yes, your right, 2 arguments are required (note the indexers are required to post back to a collection but I think I have the format wrong)

Comment: @StephenMuecke : So should i add every item in the list like this? formdata.append('[0].id',1); ?

Comment: Yes, that correct (just tested it myself)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thanks stephen, Please add your answer so that i can mark it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to post back to a collection, you would need to construct the data with indexers so it can be bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`

```
....
formdata.append('[0].id', 1);
formdata.append('[0].price', 5);
formdata.append('[1].id', 2);
formdata.append('[1].price', 6);

$.ajax({
  url: url
  data: formdata,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  type: 'POST'
});
```